# What should the referee do when a team doesn't want to play a large amount of added time?

Tags: rules

If there is at least 5 minutes of injury time, but the team that is losing doesn't want the extra time added, what should the referee do?

Comment: Is this question about football?

Answer (score 4):

What either team wants is irrelevant. Time is determined by the referee alone, and the added time exists for a reason: to make up the playing time lost by excessive stoppages. The time should be added on, and played out.

A sensible referee may know enough about the competition to be aware of what impact a change to the score might have, but even in the case that it has no effect on any standings, should not reduce the game just on a whim.

Comment: As a referee in rugby union I am aware of games state and likely effect on the league and will very definitely use my discretion to not pay injury time or other over time.

Comment: As the question assumes the existence of added time, it is obviously not about rugby, which doesn't have it, so I'm not sure how that is relevant here.

Comment: hi. Please see https://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=5 section 5 and 6 we have added time and injury time.  In the professional game there is a time keeper who stops and starts the clock based on the referees instructions.  This is purely for TV.  At amature level we keep track and play.  So I have a watch that gives me two timers. Elapsed time and stop start.